# Querying many to many relation graphql

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have my model many to many relation in my model:

Posts have many categories and categories might have many posts
`type Post 
{
  id: Int,
  userId: Int,
  title: String,
  category: [Category]
}`

```
         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | categoryId | postId
```

----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+--------
 2018-08-23 01:47:42.305+04 | 2018-08-23 01:47:42.305+04 |          1 |      2

through a PostCategories table.

when I try to Query categories on posts im getting null as result, query:

```
  {
  post(id:2){
    category {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "post": {
      "category": null
    }
  }
}
```

question is, what im doing wrong and should i add custom resolver which will get all the categories by postId.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in github but basically the category field didn’t have a resolver!

Comment: could you link to the issue or post an example?